# Difference between HTTP Splitting AND HTTP Smuggling?

Tags: security, http

What is Major Difference between HTTP Splitting HTTP Smuggling?

What is Major Similarities HTTP Splitting HTTP Smuggling?

Answer (score 2):

**HTTP splitting** is the fact of splitting **responses** or **requests** in HTTP (most often responses). You have several ways of doing that. Some applications will forgot to forbid end of lines in hostnames used in custom HTTP redirect (30x), for example, or in the past browsers could be tricked in splitting request when using end of lines in Digest HTTP Authentication usernames.

When you have this sort of issue (application flaws) you can build attacks triggering the final user (like with XSS), making users requesting an url, using the splitting to inject content in the first response and having the regular response discarded as an extra response. Which means you can split the request but also inject the response content from an url, that's a very specific combination, the url can carry the whole attack.

But splitting can also be done without application flaws, using directly a flaw in the protocol parsing by an HTTP server (like double `Content-Length` headers). The url does not carry the attack. Here splitting is a fact, (one request or response *is* splitted after the attack), but has no direct consequence. That's the tool.

**HTTP Smuggling** is a more global thing, using HTTP splitting, but not only. Without an application flaw, to perform a complete smuggling attack (leading to cache poisoning or security filters bypass), you need also transmitters, web agents like proxies which carry the splitting attack, and targets (like caches) which are impacted by the splitting.

[This post may interest you for details](http://regilero.github.io/security/english/2015/10/04/http_smuggling_in_2015_part_one/#toc13).

Comment: I do think that this is the most logic view on how to define these terms. Just as a quick side note: These two terms seem to be interpreted differently among different sources and it might be helpful if anyone added something like an authoritative definition.

Comment: Some may say that smuggling is only the fact of hiding a request, but you cannot hide anything if you cannot reveal it later, i.e use a splitting issue. But here are some links: [http://projects.webappsec.org/w/page/13246928/HTTP%20Request%20Smuggling](Req Smuggling) [http://projects.webappsec.org/w/page/13246930/HTTP%20Response%20Smuggling](Resp Smuggling) [http://projects.webappsec.org/w/page/13246929/HTTP%20Request%20Splitting](Req Splitting) [http://projects.webappsec.org/w/page/13246931/HTTP%20Response%20Splitting](Resp splitting)

Answer (score 0):

exploiting weaknesses of the web application or 
peculiarities in the way different agents interpret 
HTTP messages. 
This section will analyze two different attacks that
target specific HTTP headers:

The first attack exploits a lack of input sanitization 
which allows an intruder to insert CR and LF characters 
into the headers of the application response and to 'split' 
that answer into two different HTTP messages. The goal of
the attack can vary from a cache poisoning to cross site 
scripting.

In the second attack, the attacker exploits the fact
 that some specially crafted HTTP messages can be parsed
 and interpreted in different ways depending on the agent
 that receives them. HTTP smuggling requires some level
 of knowledge about the different agents
 that are handling the HTTP messages (web server, proxy, firewall)
 and therefore will be included only in the
 Gray Box testing section.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_HTTP_Splitting/Smuggling_(OTG-INPVAL-016)